# How is the use of virtual consoles controlled in Debian 12

Tags: linux, x11, xorg, virtual-consoles

I noticed that in Debian 12 (amd64, but I guess that's independent of the platform actually), when a user logs into the graphical UI (Xorg based with nvidia), the GDM3 server no longer is active on :0 and switching users is not available as prominently as it used to be in older Debian distributions. Also, when going to the text virtual console with Ctrl-Alt-F[1-7] not getty process seems to be activated by default nowadays.

This causes problems when I start an X server for remote rendering with TurboVNC and VirtualGL because startx then places the newly created X server port on :0 and prevents GDM3 from relaunching. Also, I can't simply enter a text console when the graphics is hosed.

I did not find any mention of those changes in the bookworm release notes, so I wondered if I could get the old behaviour back? And on another note, if not, if there is some command-line tool to query the next available X server slot above a certain threshold? SSH X11 forwarding seems to be using to not interfere with X servers launched by GDM3, which I would like to emulate here.

Comment: Since gdm wants it, why use `:0` when starting xinit? `xinit -- :9` will ensure that there is no conflict with gdm.

Comment: @xhienne Hardcoding a 9 here can only be done once. What I would like is an option to xinit that basically says "choose 10 or anything higher not currently occupied, but stay out of the 0-9 range".

Comment: If this is supposed to be a headless server, just remove GDM with `sudo systemctl stop gdm && sudo systemctl disable gdm` and reenable it when connected to VNC.  Then remember to stop it when logging out.